# Command to check if current user has permissions to read serial port

Tags: linux, permissions, serial-port, tty, read-write

So when you plug in a for example usb-serial converter to a modern Linux, it gets automatically mapped as `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Now the user who wants to read it has to be `root` or belong to the group the device is created ie. `dialout`.

I know that if I add `udev rule` for the device, I can read-write without issues, but is there some easy/quick way to check if we have read-write rights to that port ? This way it would be easy to create a exception handling function that would add the necessary udev rule..

I would like to avoid trying to open some serial program to it (ie. `minicom`) to see failure and catching the result of that, but something cleaner and invisible to the user.

Comment: That would simply be reading off permission bits of the device node `/dev/ttyUSB0` itself with stat(2) and comparing your `getuid()/getgid()` with them.